# Why does "vagrant up" fail with a 64bit client?

Tags: windows-8, vagrant

I'm trying to start a vagrant box. This box is a 64bit Linux (Ubuntu Trusty) and I'm on Windows 8.1 x64.

When I try to start the box, it will repeatedly print:

```
default: Warning: Connection timeout. Retrying...
```

I'm sure the vagrant config is fine, the machine works great on a similar host with Windows 7 x64.

[Intel VT-x disappeared after upgrading to Windows 8](https://superuser.com/questions/500166/intel-vt-x-disappeared-after-upgrading-to-windows-8)

Answer (score 0):

When using Vagrant (or VirtualBox for that matter) on Windows 8, there are several possible issues. As a first measure, it is helpful to start the virtual machine in the VirtualBox GUI where you get better error feedback:

[image]

One possible reasons for this issue is having the Hyper-V feature enabled. Having the Hyper-V feature enabled can cause virtualization features not being advertised correctly. Disable the feature and retry.

Additional information: [Intel VT-x disappeared after upgrading to Windows 8](https://superuser.com/questions/500166/intel-vt-x-disappeared-after-upgrading-to-windows-8)