# Intel HAXM on Windows 10

Tags: windows-10-preview, intel-haxm

For the purposes of developing Android apps and testing them in emulators, I need to install Intel HAXM. In the past I had an issue with Intel HAXM saying it could not be installed even though it could be because Hyper-V was enabled. After upgrading to Windows 10, Intel HAXM stopped working for me. I checked to make sure that Hyper-V was disabled, and it was not, so I disabled it and restarted. After doing that, it is still not working. Any idea why? I tried reinstalling Intel HAXM with compatibility mode for Windows 8 enabled, but doing so did not work.

Comment: I am  facing the Same problem

Comment: I had numerous other issues with my upgrade, so I ended up reimaging my machine. After that, installing Intel HAXM worked flawlessly after I uninstalled virtualization.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure what caused the issue, but I can tell you that the issue is not caused by incompatibility with Windows 10, as I was able to get Intel HAXM working on my system after performing a clean install of Windows 10 to resolve other issues that I was having on my computer.

Comment: Could it be that you had Hyper-V installed before the reinstallation and not afterwards?

Comment: with Hyper-V on, other hypervisors wouldn't be able to use VT any more http://superuser.com/a/506766/241386

Answer (score 0):

If you have any Antivirus installed they can create this kind of issues.

I had avast installed and it was blocking my Visualization. Option was under troubleshoot.

Comment: In my case, I use Malwarebytes.